# Padding is not functioning properly, changes made in percents, ems and pixels

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, padding

I am trying to add padding around link in a vertical navigation menu I am making for a bakery site.

However when I make changes either the page becomes all out of whack, there is no changes at all, the whole menu moves or the padding disturbs the hover sequence and certain links are not highlighted when hovering over them.

I tried making changes in %, em's and pixels, but I get nothing still.

Iam using chrome and sublime text btw, if that helps.

Here is the HTML:

```
<!-- NAVIGATION LINKS-->
<div id = "navibar">
    <nav>

        <a class = "navibar" href = "aboutthebakery.html"> ABOUT THE BAKERY </a>
</br>
        <a class = "navibar" href = "bakeryselection.html"> BAKERY SELECTIONS </a>
</br>
        <a class = "navibar" href = "viewthemenu.html">VIEW THE MENU </a>
</br>
        <a class = "navibar" href = "visitalocation.html"> VISIT A LOCATION </a>
</br>
        <a class = "navibar" href = "http://example.com/--.html"> WEDDINGS & OCCASIONS </a>

</br>
        <a class = "navibar" href = "http://example.com/--.html"> CATERING 
        </a>
    </nav>
</div>
```

Here is the CSS (I changed everything to 0% just now):

```
/* NAVIGATION DIV CONTAINING LINKS */
#navibar {
    text-align: center;

    margin-top: 3%;
    margin-right: 48%;
    margin-bottom: 0%;
    margin-left: 8%;

}

.navibar {
    margin-top: 0%;
    margin-right: 0%;
    margin-bottom: 0%;
    margin-left: 0%;

    padding-top: 0%;
    padding-right: 0%;
    padding-bottom: 0%;
    padding-left: 0%;

    color: #000000;

    text-decoration: none;

    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: Verdana; 
}

.navibar:hover {
    color: #c92727;

    text-decoration: none;

    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: Verdana; 
}
```

Comment: Global padding and margins will mess with your padding. Look into `box-sizing:` here: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-sizing.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get rid of the `<br>`'s and make the links block-level elements. Inline-block elements can have padding, however it's the combination of inline-block and `<br>` that's causing your issue. `<br>` doesn't respect margin/padding very well.
Try using

```
.navibar {
    display: block;
    padding: 10px 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you explain why making it `block` element will help? cause as far as i know inline elements can have padding too.

Comment: You're completely right, inline elements can have padding, but the problem here is that they're only stacking vertically because you've used the `<br>` tags, which don't respect margin/padding very well. If it's a matter of them being on a horizontal line, with left and right padding that will work just fine.

Comment: Thanks Josh, however now the links run to each side of the page on that line and are clickable. I was trying to avoid this and tried to use the float property to side the div together but this is just making the links act as if they are inline. I tried using the inline-block but no luck with that either.

Comment: Try something like this: http://codepen.io/the_ruther4d/pen/6534e761788daa741ebde3c82af05497/